# Notification displays in notification bar even when app is open

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

My app is having local notifications with action buttons : snooze and dismiss. The problem is that, when my app is open I have displayed notification in popup. It displays popup and notification in notification bar also displays. 
As a general scenario app does not display notification in notification bar when it is in foreground. But I can see the both.

Can not figure out what is happening here. 
I have handled the notification in didReceiveLocalNotification method as below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

 UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
 if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp"
                                                    message:notification.alertBody
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"SNOOZE",@"DISMISS",nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];
 }
}
```

and below is my didFinishLaunching method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"SNOOZE"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:kNotificationActionSnooze];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
    action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action2 setTitle:@"DISMISS"];
    [action2 setIdentifier:kNotificationActionDismiss];
    [action2 setDestructive:NO];
    [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:kNotificationCategoryIdent];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert| UIUserNotificationTypeSound| UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

   }

 return YES;
}
```

see the images below :

[image]

[image]

Comment: your app is in foreground and the OS shows the notification popup in the status bar too ?

Comment: can you show didReceiveRemoteNotification ?

Comment: No coding in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: yes, it is showing in notification bar as well as a popup that I have coded in didreceiveLocalNotification

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

 UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
 if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
  {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyApp"
                                                    message:notification.alertBody
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"SNOOZE",@"DISMISS",nil];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
 }
}
```

cancelLocalNotification when your app in UIApplicationStateActive.

hope it's help :)

Comment: Yes, it worked! :) You are always there to help me. Thank you :D @balkaran